# How to set a minimum distance between components in OrCAD PCB Designer?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, orcad, cadence

I am using OrCAD PCB Designer Professional 17.4 and I can't setup the minimum distance between components. This is the "DFA Constraints Dialog" from Allegro in which you can make the setup, but my software doesn't have this option.

[image]

This is how my constraints menu looks, you can see that I can't choose between mils or mm, nor do I have the "Apply" button. My grid is set to mm, so I would want to have the minimum distance between components to be 0.5mm, nothing happens if I put the components closer than that, I won't get any DRC error.

[image]

This is how the error should be represented in the editor:
[image]

Here are some components that I placed, and u can see that the distance between the components is less than 0.5mm and I don't get any DRC error:

[image]